# Externalize configuration using ConfigMap with Spring Boot Kubernetes

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud-kubernetes

I'm trying to externalize my Spring Boot configuration using `ConfigMap`s in Kubernetes. I've read [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/docs/current/reference/html/#configmap-propertysource) and added the dependency on my pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-fabric8-config</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Set my `spring.application.name` as `webapp` and created a `ConfigMap` from a YAML file:

```yaml
spring:
  web:
    locale: en_US
    locale-resolver: fixed
```

Using this command:

```
kubectl create configmap webapp \
--namespace webapp-production \
--from-file=config.yaml
```

But when my application starts I get the following error:

```
Can't read configMap with name: [webapp] in namespace: [webapp-production]. Ignoring.
io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure executing: GET at: https://IP/api/v1/namespaces/webapp-production/configmaps/webapp. Message: Forbidden!Configured service account doesn't have access. Service account may have been revoked. configmaps "webapp" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:webapp-production:default" cannot get resource "configmaps" in API group "" in the namespace "webapp-production".
```

I couldn't find any more info in the docs on how to configure access other than this:

> You should check the security configuration section. To access config maps from inside a pod you need to have the correct Kubernetes service accounts, roles and role bindings.

How can I grant the required permissions?

Comment: I would mount the file from the `configmap` into the pod and read the config in spring boot like a regular file.

Comment: Yes @Shmuel I thought the same but that way I would lose the hot replace feature as far as I understood

Comment: this has nothing to do with spring per-se, it's RBAC rules of your cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it solved by creating an specific `ServiceAccount` and setting the deployment template `spec.serviceAccountName`:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: webapp-service-account
  namespace: webapp-production
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: webapp-cluster-role
  namespace: webapp-production
# Grant access to configmaps for external configuration
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["configmaps"]
    verbs: ["get"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: webapp-cluster-role-binding
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: webapp-cluster-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: webapp-service-account
    namespace: webapp-production
```